# How to efficiently move the keyboard cursor

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, ide, text-editor

```
public class Hello2{
    public staic int sum(int n, int m)
    {
        return n + m; // here is cursor
    }

    //I want move to cursor here
}
```

I want to move down the cursor under bracket

Is there a efficient way to move down the brackets rather than the arrow keys on the keyboard?

Comment: Where does your cursor start?  And do you just want to move below the next bracket from wherever you are?

Comment: `// here is cursor` is start

Comment: and I want to move cursor to `//I want to move cursor here`

Comment: I want to move cursor After writing one method

Comment: In this case, Ctrl+Shift+P followed by Ctrl+Return. But more generally, hit Alt+Shift+Up until you have selected the desired content (in your case the method), jump to the end of the selection by hitting the right arrow key and insert a new line below the current line with Ctrl+Return.

Comment: Isn't it possible not to use the keyboard arrows?

Comment: You can specify your own shortcuts not using the arrow keys, e.g. for _Select Enclosing Element_ (which is by default Alt+Shift+Up) and _Insert Line Below Current Line_ (by default Shift+Enter). These two commands should suffice to do what you want.

Comment: You can do what you want with a macro - it is a little complicated to set up.  But then it is one keybinding.  Do you want to see it?

Comment: I thought there would be a way for eclipse to support moving the cursor behind the brackets created by auto bracket. I'll just use the arrow keys rather than making it difficult.

Comment: There is the _Go to Matching Bracket_ (Ctrl+Shift+P) that places the cursor before the closing bracket which is something you need more often than placing the cursor behind it. For nested brackets you can use _Select Enclosing Element_. None of this is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl + n`  move cursor to next line

`enter` line feed

`enter` line feed

here you are

Comment: `ctrl + n` moves cursor to next line??

Comment: yes. It is default behavior defined in the keybinding.json. you can have a try.